# Why is ng-include not showing anything?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I have an index file that is using ng-include to bring in the header. here is my index file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <title>{{page.title}}</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/libs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/libs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/libs/animate.css/animate.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/libs/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/styles/style.min.css">
        <script src="../dist/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.map"></script>
        <script src="../dist/libs/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.map"></script>
        <script src="../dist/libs/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../dist/libs/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>

        <script src="../dist/js/controllers.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../dist/js/routes.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../dist/js/app.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="praxis">
        <div ng-include="partials/header.html"></div>
        <div ng-view></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am not getting any errors and my controller is loading my ng-view.

here is the header file:

```
<div id="preloader">
    <div id="status"> </div>
</div>
<div id="sb-site">
    <div class="boxed">
        <header id="header-full-top" class="hidden-xs header-full">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="header-full-title">
                    <h1 class="animated fadeInRight">Code<span>.<strong>Praxis</strong></span></h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
    </div>
</div>
```

does the path need to based off of where the app is running or where the index file is located?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should provide a string in your case, note single quotes around filepath:

```
<div ng-include="'partials/header.html'"></div>
```

From documentation:

> angular expression evaluating to URL. If the source is a string constant, make sure you wrap it in single quotes, e.g. src="'myPartialTemplate.html'".

Comment: That didn't do anything. I was under the impression that when you used <anything ng-include=""> that you didn't need to single quote the string. Maybe I am wrong, but it still didn't make a difference.

Comment: You should wrap path in single quotes. If template still doesn't show up, check the path in console, most likely you have 404, and you need to adjust the path. Make sure that there is `partials/header.html` path relative to index.html.

Comment: that was it. my path was off by one folder. I never thought to check console. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`ng-include` evaluates angular expression  to URL. If the source is a string constant, make sure you wrap it in single quotes, e.g. `src="'myPartialTemplate.html'"` so your code should be:

```
<div ng-include="'partials/header.html'"></div>
```

[see](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) in detail

Answer (score 0):

I think you must write it like this:

```
<div ng-include src="'partials/header.html'"></div>
```

With the src attribute.